# How to sort multiple columns with different orders in pandas?

Tags: pandas

How do I sort a data frame using multiple columns such that each column is sorted in different order? For example, the primary sort key is column 'A' in ascending order and secondary sort key is column 'B' in descending order.

Comment: df.sort_values(['A', 'B'], ascending=[True, False])

Comment: Thanks, it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

The method [df.sort_values](https://techblog.bozho.net/tips-for-identifying-and-debugging-problems/) has a parameter `ascending` wich can be a boolean or a list of booleans.

```
df.sort_values(['A', 'B'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```